# Using Saxon's DocumentBuilder with JAXB emits a warning about validation

Tags: java, jaxb, saxon

I have an application that uses JAXB (Moxy) and Saxon for running XPath expressions.  Everything works as expected, but Saxon's DocumentBuilder emits this warning:

```
XML Parser does not recognize the feature http://xml.org/sax/features/validation
```

Code:

```
Processor proc = new Processor(false);
DocumentBuilder builder = proc.newDocumentBuilder();
XdmNode doc = builder.build(new JAXBSource(jaxbContext, jaxbObject));//The warning occurs here
...
```

I think what's going on is JAXB is using a StaX parser and Saxon uses SAX.  So when Saxon attempts to set the above property on the StaX parser, it fails.

Is there a way to prevent Saxon from setting that property when building the document or, at the very least, suppress that warning?  I've tried setting a bunch of different properties on the Processor, but none of them worked.  I don't need validation anyway since the document has already been validated and read into a JAXB object.

EDIT: I've been trying to override the errorListener on the Processor, DocumentBuilder, and the JAXBSource, but that message is not going through any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll look into this a bit more closely, but the first thing to say is that JAXBSource extends SAXSource, and Saxon treats it exactly like it treats any other SAXSource. The warning in the JAXB documentation "Thus in general applications are strongly discouraged from accessing methods defined on SAXSource" is vacuous - applications (like Saxon) when they are defined to accept an object of class X, don't in general take any notice of advice given in the specifications of a subclass of X that they have never heard of.

The status of the property "http://xml.org/sax/features/validation" is a little unclear. IIRC the SAX specifications don't say that every XMLReader must recognize this property, but they do define it as the only way of requesting DTD expansion, and an XSLT processor needs DTD expansion to take place; if the XMLReader doesn't do DTD expansion then the transformation may fail in unpredictable ways, so a warning is justified.

The cleanest way of suppressing the warning is probably to supply an XMLReader that *does* recognise this property, and delegate from there to an XMLReader that doesn't recognise it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class SaxonLogger extends StandardLogger {
    @Override
    public void warning(String message) {
        if(!message.contains("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation")) {
            System.err.println(message);
        }
    }
}
...
proc.getUnderlyingConfiguration().setLogger(logger);
```

This will at least suppress those pesky messages.  However, I would still like to find a better solution.